# Spring Boot - Is there a way to create folders with date parameter names?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data

I would like to know if there is any method or function in Spring Boot that allows you to create folders with names of year, month and day, and that they are subsequently created with the current system date?

**Like this example:**

```
Year: 2023 --
|           |
|           Month: 05 --
|           |          |
|           |          Day: 15
|           |               16
|           |               17
|           Month: 06 --
|                      |
|                      Day: 01
|                           02
|                           03
Year: 2024 --
            |
            Month: 01 --
            |          |
            |          Day: 03
            |               04
            |               05
            Month: 02 --
                       |
                       Day: 01
                            02
                            03
```

I would appreciate any comments and support that gives me the solution.

Comment: You can it without Spring with the Java Date and Files API.

Comment: If your target is to store log files you could also utilize slf4j/logback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Task like this is not in the focus of Spring Boot framework, so the direct answer to your question is: No, there is nothing particular in spring boot that can help you.
Having said that, Java has enough APIs to achieve this task:

- Use java time API to get the current day, month, year
- Use File API to create files, folders, etc.